# ownCloud not installing due to magic quotes error

Tags: php-extension, magic-quotes-gpc, owncloud

i want to install ownCloud on my server for personal use but it is giving error.

"Magic Quotes is enabled. ownCloud requires that it is disabled to work properly.
Magic Quotes is a deprecated and mostly useless setting that should be disabled. Please ask your server administrator to disable it in php.ini or in your webserver config."

"PHP modules have been installed, but they are still listed as missing?
Please ask your server administrator to restart the web server."

the img is : http://www.imageshack.com/i/f6zb8yp
i have tried to disable magicquotes by .htaccess file and php.ini but still it is giving error

i am using a linux-os hosting from godaddy.plz someone help.

Comment: Did you restart the server after disabling magic quotes? If yes, can you try if you can reproduce this with the latest ownCloud? 7.0.2?

Comment: thanks it had some server problem which i solved through htaccess